# TMUX key bindings

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux

I have a problem with TMUX key bindings. When I'm working on a terminal pane, if I press ctrl+pgup, it should scroll the screen one page up, as a normal terminal, but it doesn't.

Also, while using VIM, I have mapped  to do some actions, but this key combination is not called.

Any TMUX expert there?.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your shell and terminal are sending the appropriate escape sequences to one-another to indicate non-alphanumeric keys. For example, I use `tmux` with `zsh` in `urxvt`. I had quite a few problems with keys acting inappropriately (like enter insert mode and adding `[3~`) until I made sure my shell was communicating the appropriate key-bindings with:

```
# .zshrc
bindkey '\e[1~' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[4~' end-of-line
bindkey '\e[6~' down-line-or-search
bindkey '\e[5~' up-line-or-search
bindkey '\e[3~' delete-char
```

If this is your problem, yours are not likely to be the same, but you should be able to find resources specific to your shell and terminal emulator.

Comment: I too use zsh, with gnome-terminal, and I also have those key bindings. Without tmux the terminal works correctly, that's why I think my problem should be solved by modifying my .tmux.conf (but I don't know how).

Comment: oh interesting. I'll have to keep thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

use the tmux command `setw -g xterm-keys on`

you may also need to add this to your `~/.vimrc`

```
if &term == "screen"
    set t_kN=^[[6;*~
    set t_kP=^[[5;*~
endif
```

Comment: Thanks again sleepynate, but it does not work. In VIM, when I press ctrl+pgup, instead of moving to previous tab, the text is changed to Upper Case. Also, in the zsh shell, when I press ctrl+pgup, a "~5" is shown.

Comment: I must add, in my ~/.zshrc I have "bindkey -e"

Comment: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Key_Bindings <--- and you have all of these set?

Comment: Sleepynate, I added them to my .zshrc, but gave up on TMUX, I replaced it by Terminator.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following keybindings to your `.zlogin`:

```
bindkey '\e[3~' delete-char  
bindkey '^r' history-beginning-search-backward  
bindkey '^g' history-beginning-search-forward  
bindkey -s '^l' '^qcls\n'
```

Comment: can you explain us what it does, i see a potential answer.

Comment: [zlogin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22645_01/html/817-1592/z.login.ov-2.html) Has nothing to do with tmux